# Moda, media y mediana JAVA

Tags: java

necesito hacer un programa que cálcule la media aritmética, la moda y la mediana de tres número que ingrese el usuario, usando switch.
Espero puedan asesorarme ya que no me va muy bien con los arrays. 
Esto es lo que llevo:

```
int num1, num2,num3,dato;
   num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el primer número: "));
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el segundo número: "));
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tercer número: "));

    dato = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Elija una opción:\n"
            + "1. Media aritmética\n"
            + "2. Moda aritmética"
            + "3. Mediana aritmética"
            + "4. Salir"));
    switch (dato){
        case 1: 

    }
```

Comment: Y que errores obtienes al momento?

Comment: No necesitas usar ningún array... Ahora en el switch tendrás que hacer las operaciones necesarias para calcular la media, moda o mediana, en función de lo que se seleccionó.

Comment: Te dejo el link con la solución: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IjyFCd

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bueno, antes que nada, para que puedas comprender bien el ejercicio. Observa que son y cual es la fórmula de **la Moda, Media y la Mediana**. Puedes observarlo dando click en el siguiente enlace:* https://www.portaleducativo.net/octavo-basico/790/Media-moda-mediana-rango

*Ahora bien, he realizado el ejercicio pidiendo la cantidad de números que se van a ingresar para resolver cada operación aritmética y posteriormente se pedirá cada número. No lo quise limitar solo a 3 datos, pero son bien recibidos. ya es cuestión de que lo adaptes y se que aun hay cosas que no validé pero creo que ya es cuestión de cada quien realizar ciertas validaciones.*

*En mi caso no usé los ***JOptionPane.showInputDialog*** pero igual puedes reemplazar los sysout por ello. Mi código es el siguiente:*

```js
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverFlow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {

      System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de numeros a operar: ");
      int cantidad = input.nextInt();

      if (cantidad > 2) {
        String result = "";
        int i = 0;
        int[] numeros = new int[cantidad];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < cantidad; idx++) {
          System.out.println("Digite el número " + (idx + 1));
          numeros[idx] = input.nextInt();
        }

        do {
          switch (i) {
            case 0:
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Calculamos la moda aritmetica");

              List < Integer > acumulado = calcularModa(numeros);

              if (acumulado.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("La moda no existe");
              } else {
                result = "";
                for (int valor: acumulado) {
                  if (valor > 0) {
                    result += valor + ",";
                  }
                }

                System.out.println("La moda es: " + result.substring(0, result.length() - 1));
              }

              break;
            case 1:
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Calculamos la media aritmetica");

              result = calcularMedia(numeros);

              System.out.println(result);
              break;
            case 2:
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Calculamos la mediana aritmetica");

              result = calcularMediana(numeros);

              System.out.println("La mediana es: " + result);
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          i++;
        } while (i < 3);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      input.close();
    }
  }

  private static List < Integer > calcularModa(int[] numeros) {

    int c = 0;
    int veces = 0;
    int conteoMayor = 0;
    List < Integer > acumulado = new ArrayList < > ();

    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
      c = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < numeros.length; k++) {

        if (j == numeros[k]) {
          c++;
        }
      }

      if (veces <= c) {
        veces = c;
        if (c > 1 && c < numeros.length) {
          if (acumulado.size() == 0 || (conteoMayor > 0 && conteoMayor == c)) {
            conteoMayor = c;
            acumulado.add(j);
          } else if (conteoMayor < c) {
            conteoMayor = c;
            acumulado.clear();
            acumulado.add(j);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return acumulado;
  }

  private static String calcularMedia(int[] numeros) {
    double valor = 0;
    String result = "(";
    for (int numero: numeros) {
      valor += (numero * 1.0);
      result += numero + " + ";
    }
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 2);
    result += ")/" + numeros.length + " = " + valor / numeros.length;

    return result;
  }

  private static String calcularMediana(int[] numeros) {

    // Ordenamos los numeros de menor a mayor
    Arrays.sort(numeros);

    String result;

    if (numeros.length % 2 == 0) {
      int pos = (numeros.length - 2) / 2;
      result = "" + (((numeros[pos] * 1.0) + numeros[pos + 1]) / 2);
    } else {
      int pos = (numeros.length - 1) / 2;
      result = "" + numeros[pos];
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

*Por cierto el código lo puse a funcionar ingresando minimo 3 numeros. Espero te sirva.*

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, gran aporte.